# "look at something from a side" or "look at something from aside"?

Tags: grammar

Here is the context:

> I have looked at you in the the dress from the front, and I would like to look at you from **a side**/**aside**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct version is "...from **the side**."

Be very careful with the phrase "look aside."  It means "to look to one side," usually because you cannot tolerate looking at whatever is in front of you.

So while the following sentence is correct:

> I have looked at you in the the dress from the front, and now I need to look aside.

it is also **extremely insulting**.  It means that you have looked at the listener from the front, but have found the result so ugly that you must look away for a moment to compose yourself.

Answer (score 3):

We say "look at you from the side" or "look at you from one side". Not "aside", not "a side".